# Recalculate the progress percentage according to potential errors

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, progress-bar

I have a progress that advances according to three operation.
The first operation takes 10 seconds, the second operation takes 15 seconds and the third operation takes 15 seconds.
The progress percentage can be calculated using this formula:

```
elapsedTime/totalTime * 100%
```

where totalTime is 10+15+15 = 40 seconds.

Suppose now that each operation can have an error that is calculated at the end of each operation (for example the first operation takes 3 seconds more, so the time to complete it is 13 seconds).
What is the new way to recalculate the progress percentage so that the progress 
always goes forward (it should proceed slowly but never go backwards)?

The Maximum of my progress is set to 100.

Comment: I wouldnt even try to estimate the time per process. Maybe a slow computer will execute this tool, it would take more time. This isnt accurate!  I would rather split the percentage by the count of processes. Sure not every percentage would have taken the same.

Comment: Also: You can add your fallback-processes to the total count of processes. This way the progress would just move slower, but never fall back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if  you added the error_Time to both sides? I mean something like this:

```
(op1+ error_Time_op1 + op2 +op3 )/(totalTime + error_Time_op1 ) * 100%
```

Answer (score 1):

increase the `totalTime` by the amount that the error has added to the overall progress

```
totalTime + error_time
```

for the progress to go always forward you should freeze the display at the value when the error happens and only proceed to update when the newly_calculated percentage exceeds the remembered value.

image you are at the end of operation 2:

```
totalTime  = 40;
elapsedTime = 25;

old_progress = 25 / 40 * 100 [62.5%]
```

then the error occurs:

```
errorTime = 3;
totalTime  = 40 + errorTime  ;
elapsedTime = 25;

new_progress = 25 / 43 * 100 [58.1%]
```

now you wait until the `new_progress` value exceeds the `old_progess` value and then you can update again. This way it will never go backwards

Comment: This would set the percentage down. Still a question if @MartinaLabMath wants to have this.

Comment: @C4u It took me a while to write the rest of the post.